# Lithuanian letters split text into words in xkcd's simple writer (Ace Editor)

Tags: javascript, split, editor, ace-editor, words

I have stumbled upon a tool, which checks if the words used in the text are from top 1000 most commonly used words (in English, or maybe based on some sort of database) - http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/

I am very interested how it is built and I am wondering, why Lithuanian characters such as **ąčęėįšųūž are treated as word boundaries**?

As I see, charset is set to UTF-8, so these letters should not be mistreated.
I am considering building a similar tool for Lithuanian language and knowing on what criteria words are split or which part of the Ace editor code is responsible would be very useful.

Ace Editor code: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src/ace.js

Comment: It's open source so why don't you try figuring out yourself first?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an outsourcing request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ąčęėįšųūž are not considered as word boundaries in ace, you can check that by double clicking on a word with one of them

But custom mode that http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/ uses http://xkcd.com/simplewriter/ace/src-min/mode-upwriter.js
doesn't consider them as word characters and uses `/[a-zA-Z]+/` as a regexp

```
this.$rules = {
"start": [
    {
        "token" : "suffix",
        "regex" : "['’][a-zA-Z]+"
    },
    {
        "token" : "allowed",
        "regex" : "\\b(?:" + window.__WORDS + ")\\b",
        "caseInsensitive": true
    },
    {
        "token" : "disallowed",
        "regex" : "[a-zA-Z]+"
    }
]
```

Comment: I have made some tests with Lithuanian (LT) characters: http://regexr.com/3c28u
In the regexp field I added few correct LT words.
Something looks wrong with interpretation of LT characters. Space after LT character is not considered as a word boundary (e.g. "neš") but any non-LT letter is (e.g. "nešt"). LT character is not also (e.g. "nešš").

Comment: as i said \b in js regexps only supports english characters

Comment: Is there any possibility to overcome this?

Comment: do not use \b, depending on what you are trying to do something like `(?=[\s,;.+%?]|$)` can work (list of punctuation characters might need to be extended).
Note that the first \b is not needed in ace.

Comment: I have extended the list of punctuation characters and your suggestion works great!